Clickhouse Rabbitmq Engine Stops Working When Too Many Unacked Messages
I used the clickhouse rabbitmq engine to consume data from rabbitmq and using materialized views transfer data into the table. The table structure is given below. If I load data into rabbitmq queue (say 1 million), clickhouse reads and stores data but sometimes stops unexpectedly. No error message. Cannot drop rabbitmq engine table, it takes forever. Materialized view table can be dropped. What happens is, unacked message count increases quickly to 100.000 in my case. After reaching 100.000 unacked message, consumption stops. Only after restart does consumption start again, and after some time same scenario occurs.
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
    `data` String
)
ENGINE = RabbitMQ
SETTINGS rabbitmq_host_port = 'ip:port',
 rabbitmq_format = 'JSONAsString',
 rabbitmq_username = 'username',
 rabbitmq_password = 'password',
 rabbitmq_num_consumers = 1,
 rabbitmq_queue_consume = 1,
 rabbitmq_max_block_size = 1000,
 rabbitmq_flush_interval_ms = 2000,
 rabbitmq_queue_base = 'queue-name';

In GitHub, one guy opens a ticket for the same case but it's not closed yet.
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/54775
Clickhouse version 24.3.1.2672.
If I put data into a queue slowly (~10.000 per second), no problem occurs.
There seems to be a bug, but what I want is controlling prefetch count. I mean I don't want rabbitmq engine to retrieve more than what it can handle. unack count must be equal to the consumption count. Is there an option I am missing or using wrong? I supposed rabbitmq_max_block_size is similar to prefetch count(qos) in rabbitmq but not seem so.
Any suggestions? Kafka is not an option, unfortunately, because the project heavily relies on rabbitmq.
Additional info:
When problem occurred, rabbitmq consumer connection becomes dead in rabbitmq management console.
